# before you know it, you're

Tags: pronunciation

The following sentence is taken from the song *bleeding love*.

Before you know it, you're frozen.

Here's the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vzo-EL_62fQ

I am wondering whether "it" and "you're" are joined to sound like "itcher."

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: One could hear that in singing, easily, but not so much in everyday spoken English. Of course if you're asking about how it sounds in this particular song by a specific singer, you should post a link to a video.

Comment: The "t" is spoken with the front of the tongue and the "y" with the back of the tongue. Without precise enunciation, it is easy to slide the tongue through a middle position where "s" or "ch" are spoken.

Comment: Would native speakers pronounce that way in speech, even across the clause boundary? "Before you know it' and "you are frozen" belong to different clauses.